# Export Pandas DataFrame to CSV fails if file exists and is already open

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, ioerror

I am writing a program in Python that generates Pandas Dataframes and eventually exports them to CSV.
But if one of these CSV generated in a previous run is opened in MS Excel, then the export fails.

Example code:

```
import pandas as panda

df = panda.DataFrame({'Label': ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"], 'Value': [3.5, 2.6, 1.9]})

df.to_csv("test_export.csv")
```

Run a first time, open the CSV file in Excel, run a second time, and it produces error:
`PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'test_export.csv'`

Note that there is no problem if file is opened in Notepad or Sublime. Clearly Excel generates a "lock" on those files.

Anyone knows a workaround please?

Comment: You cannot open the file, and run the script while it still is open. You need to close it before running it again. If you do, it works just fine. The same is not true with Notepad.

Comment: I know, but it's for my end users who might not be aware and careful...

Answer (score 0):

You could, if you absolutely need to keep your Excel-file open before updating, to do the following thing, which forces ALL excel-sheets to close:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
import os

def closeFile():

    try:
        os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM excel.exe')

    except Exception:
        print("All closed")

closeFile()
```

And then do your code again

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Label': ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"], 'Value': [3.5, 2.6, 1.9]})

df.to_csv("test_export.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's a bit extreme :)

Comment: and I had to add a `time.sleep(1)` after the TASKKILL because there was still a handle on the file if you chain the calls